# Как скрыть текст (разного цвета!) под фоном до клика на него мышкой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день!

Хочу скрыть цветной текст под прямоугольником такого же цвета. Пример поправил, возможно ли это сделать для текста разных цветов?

```css
div.myHiddenBlock {
  color: green;
  background: green;
}

span.myVIPText
{
  color: red;
}

span.myVisibleBlock {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myHiddenBlock" onclick="this.className='myVisibleBlock';">
  Текст, который нужно <span class="myVIPText">скрыть</span> до клика мышкой
</div>
```

Comment: `style="background:body.color"` что за?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример:

```css
body {
  backround-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span style="color:lime;" class="myHiddenBlock">
  Текст, который нужно скрыть до клика мышкой
</span>
<span style="color:red;" class="myHiddenBlock">
  Текст, который нужно скрыть до клика мышкой
</span>
<span style="color:blue;">
  Простой текст
</span>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myHiddenBlock").each(function(ind, el) {   
    el.style.backgroundColor = $(el).css("color");
  });
   $(document).on("click", ".myHiddenBlock", function(e){
     e.target.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
   })
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Так я уже смог сделать, при явном задании цвета. Но мне нужно, чтобы был виден прямоугольник, куда тыкать мышкой, т.е. цвет фона под текстом сделать таким же, как сам цвет текста.

Comment: Если вы используете css, то лучше все стили писать в css, а в javascript коде менять только классы. Поправил пример, теперь он показывает блок.

Comment: Спасибо! Почти то, что нужно, только цвет прямоугольника нужно брать из цвета текста. Я не до конца описал пример, в идеале если цвет текста различается и прямоугольники должны быть таких же цветов.

Comment: Сделал пример с помощью jQuery. В примере - блоки которые должны изначально скрывать текст должны иметь класс "myHiddenBlock".

Comment: @Dima простите, а зачем здесь jq? ради трех строчек теперь 86Кб грузить?

Comment: Ну можно и без jquery всё сделать.Только зачем изобретать велосипед, так же проще и легче. Потом, в большинстве сайтов jquery уже включен.
Вот зачем:
1. Пройтись по элементам с помощью css селектора - просто
2. Не нужно задумываться о кроссбраузерности кода, jquery уже всё умеет.
3. Подписка на live событие нажатия по элементу, для того чтобы код срабатывал даже если html поменялся уже после рендеринга.

Comment: А как без jQuery сделать?

Comment: 1. Вместо each используйте document.getElementsByClassName (https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-1-dom-forms/)

2. Чтобы подписаться на события используйте addEventListener (или attachEvent для IE)  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854772/onclick-without-jquer , https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) ну или присваивайте функцию для поля onclick напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span style="background-color: green;" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor=document.body.style.backgroundColor;">Текст, который нужно скрыть до клика мышкой</span>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно ещё избавиться от явного задания цвета фона под текстом как здесь "style="background-color: green;", а взять его из цвета текста?